# dificuldade para trabalhar com CSS em responsividade

Tags: css

observem minha pagina;

CSS;

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#topo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width:400px;
    height:12px;

}
#menu{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;

}
```

Como faço para deixar um do lado do outro?

Comment: Coloca o código HTML também, mas terá que usar `float` ou `display:inline-block`.

Comment: se eu usar float ele não vai ficar responsivo.

Comment: já pensou em utilizar o bootstrap?

Comment: concordo com o uso do bootstrap, até mesmo para você entender melhor o comportamento responsivo... depois você pode criar seu próprio grid system

Comment: esse projeto está configurado para bootstrap, como faço para ficar responsivo?

Comment: você pode utilizar o sistema de colunas do bootstrap

Comment: Use o grid do bootstrap, é mais fácil e te evita problema na quebra do layout em determinados tipos de telas. Basta só ir adaptando para tuas necessidades.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como falado pelos comentários, acho está a melhor opção para responsividade:

**o Bootstrap** funciona com um sistema de **grids** (grades) para posicionar os elementos na página.

Esse mecanismo funciona como uma espécie de tabela abstrata, e é responsivo (responsive), orientado a dispositivos móveis (mobile first) e se ajusta de acordo com a tela (fluid), quando ela muda de tamanho ou de orientação.

> As columns (colunas), no Bootstrap, definem as divisões verticais das
>   rows (linhas) do seu layout.
>
> Columns devem estar sempre dentro das rows, e elas definem espaços na
>   row para que você coloque os itens visuais ou conteúdos que foram
>   projetados.
>
> Então, no Bootstrap, você tem linhas (rows) e colunas (columns) para
>   definir um layout. É, exatamente, como uma grade ou matriz (ou
>   tabela), porém, utilizando div’s com classes.
>
> Para criar uma column você pode criar uma div com os prefixos
>   pré-definidos pelo Bootstrap, como no exemplo:

```
<div class"container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Neste exemplo, temos uma linha (.row) com duas colunas (.col-md-6).
>
> O número seis, no final de cada classe de coluna, define o espaço que
>   ela ocupa na linha. Assim, neste exemplo, teríamos a linha (row)
>   dividida exatamente no meio por duas colunas, já que usamos o número
>   seis.
>
> Os prefixos de colunas servem para indicar em quais tipos de tela a
>   coluna vai se manter posicionada como no design principal. Os prefixos
>   têm o seguinte padrão:
>   [image: Os tipos de col]

Sugiro os links: [Como usar o grid](http://webdevacademy.com.br/tutoriais/ux/bootstrap-3-layouts-sistema-grids/), [Documentação Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)